# Best way to use multiple awaits C# .NET Blazor

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

In a Blazor app I have a file uploader that can take multiple files. When the user clicked 'upload' I used something like this:

```csharp
private async Task HandleFileUploadClicked()
{
    _isUploading = true;
    StateHasChanged();

    foreach (var file in _files)
    {
        await using var stream = file.OpenReadStream(file.Size);
        await _myService.AddFile(
            stream
        );
    }

    _isUploading = false;

    _files = new List<IBrowserFile>();
    await LoadData();

    StateHasChaged();

}
```

But I discovered this doesn't work correct. Because I am not using the result of `_myService.Addfile` the call is just fired and the code continues at `_isUploading = false;`

Then I thought maybe I should keep an array of the `AddFile` Tasks and use `Task.WaitAll` to wait for all of them. But the problem it that this waits on the UI thread, so `_isUploading = true;` and `StateHasChanged` have no effect.

My current (working) solution is something like this:

```csharp
private async Task HandleFileUploadClicked()
{
    _isUploading = true;
    StateHasChanged();
    var allOk = true;

    foreach (var file in _files)
    {
        await using var stream = file.OpenReadStream(file.Size);
        var result = await _myService.AddFile(
            stream
        );
        allOk = result != null && allOk;
    }

    _isUploading = false;

    _files = new List<IBrowserFile>();
    await LoadData();

    StateHasChaged();
}
```

But this feels like a hack.

Is there a better way to wait for multiple tasks but without blocking the UI thread?

Comment: I don't see how your working solution is different from the non-working regarding the async flow. You are awaiting the tasks in both, and you are not storing them in the second either. And while `Task.WaitAll` blocks, `Task.WhenAll` doesn't.

Comment: _"Because I am not using the result of _myService.Addfile the call is just fired and the code continues"_  is incorrect. And nothing here will "block the UI thread".

Comment: Be much clearer abnout _"this doesn't work correct"_. Provide expected and actual results.

Comment: @HenkHolterman `StateHasChanged` does not update the view when I use `Task.WaitAll`. That's why I think the UI thread waits.

Comment: Still not clear.  StateHasChanged() never updates the UI (directly), it just requests that to happpen. The UI should update with the first file but not with the 2nd or later. That StateHasChanged()  at the end has no effect.

Comment: @HenkHolterman When I use `Task.WaitAll` the effect of the first `StateHasChanged()` is not noticeable because the UI waits for the tasks to finish. That's why `Task.WhenAll` should work better. Then the view will update while the tasks run.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of Task Parller Library method Task.WhenAll(). Which will make sure that the tasks are processed in parallel.
code snippet should be as follows:

```
bool allOk = true;
try
{
    var uploadtasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach(var file in filesToUpload)
    {
        uploadtasks.Add(_myService.AddFile(file));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(uploadtasks);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    allOk = false;
}
```